# How to get related data of selected item from one ComboBox to another ComboBox in java

Tags: java, combobox, jframe

I am creating a program in which I have two comboBoxes "**jComboBox1**" & "**jComboBox2**". "jComboBox1" is retrieving all the banks from the database. 
While "jComboBox2" should bring all the accounts of the selected bank. Now, I manage to retrieve all the banks in "jComboBox1". But I do not understand how to connect it with the second comboBox.
My code is as follows.

```
package frame;

import java.beans.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.*;
//import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import java.io.*;

public class print_cheque extends javax.swing.JFrame  {
    public print_cheque() {
        initComponents();
        Connection con = null;
        //Statement st =  null;
        String query = "Select bnk_nm from d_bank_mst";
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ora10g", "payablek", "payablek");
            System.out.println("connection successful");

            java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String bank = rs.getString(1);
                jComboBox1.addItem(bank);
            }
            //con.close();
            st.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox3 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox4 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Bank Name");

        jLabel2.setText("Account No");

        jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jLabel3.setText("From Cheque No");

        jComboBox3.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jLabel4.setText("To Cheque No");

        jComboBox4.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jRadioButton1.setText("Cash");
        jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox2, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox3, 0, 253, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox4, 0, 253, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton1))
                .addContainerGap(49, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(64, 64, 64)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                .addContainerGap(82, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                             

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(print_cheque.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(print_cheque.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(print_cheque.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(print_cheque.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new print_cheque().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox3;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import java.beans.Statement;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Sher Sodha
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    Connection con = null;
    java.sql.Statement stmt = null;

    public NewJFrame() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        initComponents();
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ora10g", "payablek", "payablek");
        System.out.println("connection successful");
        String query = "Select bnk_nm from d_bank_mst";
        java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String bank = rs.getString(1);
            jComboBox1.addItem(bank);
        }

        rs.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item3", "Item 4" }));
        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jComboBox1);
        jComboBox1.setBounds(60, 32, 56, 20);

        jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        getContentPane().add(jComboBox2);
        jComboBox2.setBounds(50, 100, 56, 20);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ello");       // TODO add your handling code here:
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) evt.getSource();

        String banknm = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, banknm);

        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        ResultSet rs2 = null;

        String Query = "Select  colouumNafromme  from tablename where bnk_nm=" + banknm + " ";
        try {
            rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            while (rs2.next()) {
                try {
                    jComboBox2.addItem(rs2.getString(1));
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

---

```
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PSEUDO-CODE *all of this happens inside the ActionListener*

- The `ActionListener` for jComboBox1 needs to call `jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()`
- The string (or whatever the object type of jComboBox1) can be used to get the list of applicable Accounts from the database.
- Call `jComboBox2.removeAllItems()` to empty jComboBox2
- For each Account in the list call `jComboBox2.addItem(Account)`

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods in JComboBox like `getSelectedItem(), getSelectedIndex()` which can be used to fetch and manipulate data from them and also you can register the JComboBox with ActionListener.

For e.g.

```
jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JComboBox<String> jComboBox2 = (JComboBox<String>) event.getSource();
        String str = (String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();

        if (str.equals("A")) {
            System.out.println("AAA");
        } else if (str.equals("B")) {
            System.out.println("BBB!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: actually I am getting data from the database so I cannot hard code it. 
Do I have to create a new connection, Statement & result set inside actionlistner?